# Don't display values by using Json decode()

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I stored some values in HTML table to MySQL database. It successfully stored in the database, but when I fetched the data using `Json decode()`, the Html table nothing shows any data in the web page, but nothing error occurred.

Here is the php code:

```
 <table class="table table-bordered mb-0">
    <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Medicine Name</th>
                <th>Morning</th>
                <th>Noon</th>
                <th>Noght</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
             <tbody>

                   <?php
                require_once 'auth/dbconnection.php';

                  $sql = "SELECT * FROM prescription";
                  if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
                     if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

                         $medRecords = json_decode($row['med_records'],true);
                            if (is_array($medRecords) || is_object($medRecords)) {
                                foreach($medRecords as $key => $object) {

             ?>                 <tr>
                                      <td><?php echo $object->medname ?></td>
                                      <td><?php echo $object->morning ?></td>
                                      <td><?php echo $object->noon ?></td>
                                      <td><?php echo $object->night ?></td>                                 
                                </tr>   
                <?php
                    } }}}
                     ?>
                </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is my database table

[image]

I don't know where I went wrong. How to improve the code segments?

Comment: Check out `$medRecords` returns an array after passing `true` as second argument in `json_decode()` function. If the function returns `null` then your json encoded code in the db has invalid json format.

Comment: @unclexo I have uploaded my `database` table. Please go through this.

Comment: Well, I am not able to go through that data using the image you provided. Would you be able to provide the raw data of the `med_records` column here?

Comment: @unclexo It shows like this: `[{"medname":"","morning":"2","noon":"3","night":"4"}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that you missing the fetch itself: `$result->fetch_assoc()`
You using the var `$row` but from where?

I think you code should be as:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM prescription";
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {        <---- Notice this line
            $medRecords = json_decode($row['med_records'],true);
            if (is_array($medRecords) || is_object($medRecords)) {
                foreach($medRecords as $key => $object) {
                ...
```